# Strange for loop behavior

Tags: javascript, dom, for-loop

This code below deosn't remove "class" attribute from every node from the nodelist. Am I missing something?

`HTML`

```
<button class="choice"></button>
<button class="choice"></button>
<button class="choice"></button>
<button onclick="removeAttr()">REMOVE ATTRIBUTES</button>
```

`Javascript`

```
function removeAttr() {
    var i, buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('choice');
    for (i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
        buttons[i].removeAttribute('class');
    }
}
```

However after few clicks you'll get your wanted result, but I don't understand why...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.getElementsByClassName()` returns a live NodeList. That means that as you're removing classes those elements will no longer be in the NodeList.

You can solve the problem by looping backwards.

```
function removeAttr() {
    var i, l, buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('choice');
    for (i = 0, l = buttons.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        buttons[i].removeAttribute('class');
    }
}
```

Or you could use a while loop.

```
function removeAttr() {
    var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('choice');
    while(buttons.length) buttons[0].removeAttribute('class');
}
```

Or you could use a selection method that returns a static NodeList like `.querySelectorAll()`

```
function removeAttr() {
    var i, buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.choice');
    for (var i in Object.keys(buttons)) {
        buttons[i].removeAttribute('class');
    }
}
```